# Python. Arima. Прогнозирование временных рядов

Tags: python

Кто может объяснить, что здесь написано. Не могу найти документацию по ARIMA, по частям тоже особо информации нет:

```
import pmdarima as pm
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load/split your data
y = pm.datasets.load_wineind()
train, test = train_test_split(y, train_size=150)

# Fit your model
model = pm.auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=12)

# make your forecasts
forecasts = model.predict(test.shape[0])  # predict N steps into the future

# Visualize the forecasts (blue=train, green=forecasts)
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
plt.plot(x[:150], train, c='blue')
plt.plot(x[150:], forecasts, c='green')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Как это "Не могу найти документацию по ARIMA"? У вас что, уже отключили Google?
Ну тогда ловите прямую ссылку:

http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/classes.html#api-ref